# importing data using get or create - identity error 1062

Tags: django

I am importing data from a mssql database into mysql. Works except when it encounters the id of a previous entry. id is unique. I need to get entries that already exist so that they can be placed in the work of the day. 
Error is
IntegrityError: (1062, "Duplicate entry '001355338' for key 2")
This entry is already in the database. I need it entered for that day, but can not have it added to the table. It is already there.

```
def handle(self, *args, **options):
      #patients_local = Patient.objects.all()
      #attendings_local = Attending.objects.all()
      connection = pyodbc.connect("XXXXXXXXXXX") 
      cursor = connection.cursor()
      cursor.execute(COMMAND)
      rows = cursor.fetchall()
      for row in rows:
          # get_or_create returns (object, boolean)
          p, created = Patient.objects.get_or_create(
              first_name = row.Firstname,
              middle_name = '',
              last_name = row.Lastname,
              id = row.id,
          )
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `get_or_create` is searches with a series of `AND`'s, I'd guess that it is possible that you have one patients (or one patient ID) which has different first/middle/last combination. When none is found, that's fine: `get_or_create` makes a new one and moves on, but when there is a duplicate ID, it gets confused and raises an exception.

So your table might look like this:

```
Firstname | Lastname | Middlename | id
---------------------------------------------
Frank     | Stein    |            | 1
Franklin  | Stein    |            | 1
```

The way to get around this is to use the `defaults` parameter:

```
Patients.objects.get_or_create(id = row.id,
              defaults={'first_name': row.Firstname, 
                        'last_name': row.Lastname, 
                        'middle_name': ''})
```

You should also confirm that there are no unique Firstname, Lastname indexes in MySQL.

```
Firstname | Lastname | Middlename | id
---------------------------------------------
John      | Smith    |            | 1         # John Smith from Jamestown, VA.
John      | Smith    |            | 754567890 # John Smith from StackOverflow
```

Comment: I understand. There will be returning people, so the name may already be in the table. In this case I want to skip the entry of the name, but not the appointment, which needs to be included in that days business.